# Extra field vs two DB calls

Tags: mysql, database, mongodb, key, uuid

I do not want to expose the ID of the item. Thus I can either use UUID v1 (ordered and in binary) to group the items OR I can instead give the name of the item group to the user. The user requests the item with its group name, the server has to first make a DB call to look up the group ID and THEN go to the item table to find the items belonging to the group.

Which of these approaches are optimal in case of millions of rows in a database?

The comparision is between indexing UUID or making two database calls to first get the ID then to get the item with the ID (that is indexed).

EDIT:

This is an API application we are talking about.

Comment: Can you add an array of group names to each object as a `groups` field, then you could index that field and directly query for all items in a group by name.

Comment: @Joe Yes but is that faster than just having an array of ID's instead of name and instead making a second DB call to get the ID of the name. Then I can instead index IDs instead of strings. Is it true?